# Is it possible to somehow start an activity with a given content?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have to buttons which should start the same activity, but use a different XML file.
What I was hoping to be able to do was something like this, from "main":

button1: startActivity(new Intent(main.this, next.class, R.layout.xmlfile1));
button2: startActivity(new Intent(main.this, next.class, R.layout.xmlfile2));

I guess I could save the xml-name in the application context / with a global variable, but that wouldn't be very elegant.

Anyone know if there is any way to accomplish what I'm looking for? At the moment I'm creating duplicate class-files, and that's not really a smooth way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data to the activity by putting extra data on the Intent.
See the Intent's method `putExtra` and `getIntExtra` and friends.

The integer you put is the xml resource id.
On the activity you cat use `getIntExtra` on the activities intent (`getIntent`) to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 1):

suppose have an array of integers in the activity A:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};
```

And i want to send that variable to the activity B, so i create a new intent and use the putExtra method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("numbers", array);
startActivity(i);
```

In the activity B i get the info:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] arrayB = extras.getIntArray("numbers");
```